# How to do a "deep" / full copy of a nested sequence in Premiere Pro CS6? (i.e. constituent components are all copied)

Tags: video-editor, premiere, mac

I created a title sequence: title, with glow/fade in then fade out and made this into a nested sequence. I wanted to reuse this nested sequence in other parts of my project, but use different text content for the title in each of the other instances.

So, I copied the nested sequence several times. But when I changed the title to different text, this affected all of the nested sequence copies. So it seems that the copy creates a new 'container' but references the same components (e.g. title) as the original.

So I'm looking for a way to entirely copy a nested sequence and make duplicates of all the consituent components. Is there a way?

By the way, there seem to be three different ways to make a copy: from the contextual pop-up menu for a sequence there is 'Copy', 'Duplicate' and another method (name escapes me at the moment). I've tried all three and none of them solve my problem. I'm hoping that there is a check box somewhere that I can tick/enable to say 'copy all components'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate both your Title and your sequence, call one sequence V1...and the other V2, then take your title and call it Title V1 and title V2...then replace the title in sequence 2 with V2, then from that point on any changes made within the V1 side will not affect V2 and vise versa.

Comment: Understood and thanks. However my preference was that when Premiere Pro is copying a sequence, that it would also make true, independent copies of the components that the copy of the sequence should contain. It's inconvenient that this has to be considered manually by the user.

Comment: Yea unfortunately it just doesn't work that way...your looking for the FCP way, this is the AVID way of thinking where the title essentially is its own footage, if you want to different versions of a title, much like too different takes of a shot, then you literally need two versions of that title.

Comment: +1 and accepted - it tells me that what I want is not quite possible (yet). Thanks. Which version of FCP by the way do we see this in? I also have FCP 7 - the last (I think) version before X.

Comment: Yes when you use FCP and you duplicate a sequence everything is copied, with the exception of nested sequences, if you change a nested sequence it will change in both, but I do not recommend using nesting sequences if it can be avoided

Answer (score 4):

I also have an idea, if your sequence and titles are too complicated you can save a copy of your project and then import a sequence from it to the main project.

It's best possible solution to copy title I've found with motion titles templates.

Comment: I voted for this answer, giving you the benefit of the doubt.  It is a correct answer.  But it can be worded better, to be a more authoritative answer.  Please do edit it, writing as if you have an explanation to give, not just a hunch.

Answer (score 3):

I also bumped into this issue and couldn't find a way to create a true copy of a text layer that contains effects, etc. However, there is a way around this, it still adds 1 step to the process, but it's better than most solutions I found.

So, duplicate your title, rename then go to the original title, choose it on the timeline, copy it. Then go back to the new title you just made, right click and choose " paste attributes " from the top of the list.

There, you have the same effects on a new line of text. Lemme know if you guys find an easier method.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

We created an extension for easy and true duplication of sequences, and it's create unique copies of all items included the sequence with custom settings of naming.
https://aescripts.com/duplicate-it/

Comment: Bought it. Used it. Friggin love it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Save a copy of the file and import the nest, that way they are independent

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Don't hesitate to leave detailed instructions on what to do, next time though, with a breakdown of the steps one should take (where to click, etc) to achieve what you describe.